# Java: Cancel Future

Tags: java, concurrent.futures

I am using a `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` to create multiple futures to write parallel into a database.

`for(BusinessElement el : elements){ list.add(threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> createElement(el))); }`

So what I want to do is when one submit failed to stop all execution, means when one submit failed that it
should stop the execution of all active threads and go out from the the foreach block.

Is their any elegant solution?

Comment: [Canceling `Future` objects](https://www.ecosia.org/search?tts=st_asaf_macos&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20cancel%20future%20java) has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. How do none of those address your issue?

Comment: Is it possible to add a callable to a future object to get notified when its failed?

Comment: @sensenol I added more info to my answer, including an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use [structured concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/structured-concurrency.html):

```java
try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
    ...
    scope.fork(() -> createElement(el));
    scope.join();
}
```

If structured concurrency isn't an option, use [tascalate-concurrent](https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent). It's an implementation of `CompletionStage` that is well suited for I/O tasks, is interruptable and cascades cancellations, none of which can be said for `CompletableFuture` (itself an implementation of `CompletionStage`).

If you don't care about interruption, `CompletableFuture` is enough:

```java
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = elements.stream()
            .map(el -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> createElement(el), threadPoolExecutor))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);

CompletableFuture<Void> allDone = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
allDone.join(); //wait for all to finish or one to fail
```

After this, you can inspect if `allDone` succeeded or failed, e.g. with `allDone.isCompletedExceptionally()`, and it will fail if any of the subtasks failed. You can also extract the individual results etc. But! All tasks will *always* be submitted, and no task will *ever* be interrupted/aborted. If that's an issue, use tascalate-concurrent instead. Remember you can always turn a `CompletionStage` into a `CompletableFuture` via `toCompletableFuture()`;

> Is it possible to add a callable to a future object to get notified when its failed?

Sure. There are many callbacks on `CompletableFuture`, e.g.

- `future.exceptionally(exception -> ...)`, //handle exception
- `future.exceptionallyAsync(exception -> ...)`,
- `future.handle((result, exception) -> ...)` //handle all results
  etc.